# Performance bench marking tool for JCE provider

Tags: java, cryptography, jce

I want to test my own *JCE* provider which implements:

1. SHA1 and SHA2 MD5 digests
2. RSA (Enc/Sign/Verify)
3. HMAC

Is there any performance bench marking tool for JCE provider?

Comment: Not that I know of, but implementing this should not be too hard. Note though that the JIT requires you to: 1) make sure your output is actually used (it doesn't really matter how, as long as the output of the cryptographic algorithms is actually *required* otherwise the JIT may optimize them away) - I've even seen this happen with complete hash algos 2) you perform a few rounds before testing, or the JIT compiler will not have optimized your code yet.

Comment: Questions involving the recommendation of software tools or other resources are off-topic on Stack Overflow. This is because there is no universally accepted answer when these kinds of questions are asked, which can ultimately attract spam and dissension. Please read the following page on what kinds of questions you can ask: [help/on-topic]. That being said, if you have a specific programming question regarding the implementation of such a benchmarking tool, then by all means please ask. Otherwise, this question will inevitably be closed.